# Morphox plugins show all waves

Tags: audio, crash

I'm in trouble with my Linplug - Morphox plugin; I mean, yesterday I installed the `morphox.component` into the right folder `Macintosh-Library-Audio-plug ins- component`.

When I open Logic Pro 9 (32-bit) and I choose the new AU, I put the correct serial number and everything works perfectly.

Today when I open Logic Pro 9 again, and I choose the AU morphox, any kind of wave, in the waves window, is shown, so no sound for me, but yesterday everything was working fine, and I saw the waves in the "OSC1" and "OSC2" windows.

I've attached a pic of morphox so that you can see what I mean at the left top of the pic, two windows without any wave.

[image: Screenshot]

I tried to uninstall it, but if I remove the component and the I paste the component again, I have the same problem; I would try to delete the validation key as well, so that when I restart it, I type the validation key again and maybe it would work, but how can I completely delete all files of the component?

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: How is this a Apple products problem?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Apple software running on OS X is definitively on topic here :-)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, Logic Pro X doesn't use 32-bit plugins, only 64-bit.
I'm not sure about Logic Po 9, but I thought that was 64-bit too.
https://splice.com/blog/using-logic-pro-x-with-32-bit-plugins/

Personally, I don't use Logic, I'm Cubase - but the latest Morphox is working fine in both 32 & 64-bit mode.

Install for both is pretty much drag & drop to the correct folders, prefs/sounds in `/Library/Application Support/LinPlug/` plugs in `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins`, so I'm not sure reinstalling would help. I'd check with LinPlug that you have the latest version.  As of writing, that's v1.1.1 - http://www.linplug.com/morphox.html